# How to auto fill address using Google autocomplete and Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete

I'm new to Vue js and I'm trying to use the autocomplete API to auto fill the address fields in my form, after a User starts typing and selects an address from the dropdown menu. The code from the docs uses Vanilla javascript and I want to convert this into Vue js and integrate it into my existing form.

Inside my data, I have an object called employerProfileData and I use this on my form inputs using v-model.

```
data() {
            return {

                employerProfileData: {
                    company_name: '',
                    phone: '',
                    number_of_employees: '1-25',
                    options: [
                        { value: '1-25', text: '1-25' },
                        { value: '25-50', text: '25-50' },
                        { value: '50-100', text: '50-100' },
                        { value: '100-250', text: '100-250' },
                        { value: '250-500', text: '250-500'},
                        { value: '500-1000', text: '500-1000'}
                    ],
                    street: '',
                    city: '',
                    country: 'Canada',
                    optionsTwo: [
                        { value: 'Canada', text: 'Canada' },
                        { value: 'United States', text: 'United States' }
                    ],
                    province_state: '',
                    zip_postal: '',
                },

                errors: {},

            };
```

Right now, I'm getting the place details from the autocomplete object like this `const place = autocomplete.getPlace();`. Now, I can access the address_component like this `place.address_components` to get the values that I want to assign to my input fields, something like this.

```
mounted() {

            const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                document.getElementById("autocomplete"),
                {
                    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                        new google.maps.LatLng(43.651070, -79.347015)
                    )
                });

            function fillInAddress() {

                // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
                const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

                this.employerProfileData.street = place.address_components[0].short_name + place.address_components[1].long_name;
                this.employerProfileData.city = place.address_components[2].long_name;
                this.employerProfileData.country = place.address_components[5].long_name;
                this.employerProfileData.province_state = place.address_components[4].short_name;
                this.employerProfileData.zip_postal = place.address_components[6].short_name;

            }

            autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress);

        }
```

But it seems I can't do this in the `fillInAddress()` function and I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'street' of undefined
```

------------ UPDATED THIS WORKS: ------------

I needed to `bind.(this)` on `fillInAddress` function.
mounted() {

```
            const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                document.getElementById("autocomplete"),
                {
                    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                        new google.maps.LatLng(43.651070, -79.347015)
                    )
                });

            function fillInAddress() {

                // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
                const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

                this.employerProfileData.street = place.address_components[0].short_name + place.address_components[1].long_name;
                this.employerProfileData.city = place.address_components[2].long_name;
                this.employerProfileData.country = place.address_components[5].long_name;
                this.employerProfileData.province_state = place.address_components[4].short_name;
                this.employerProfileData.zip_postal = place.address_components[6].short_name;

            }

            autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress.bind(this));

        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be probably interested in [vue-google-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-autocomplete) package.

Example usage:

```html
<vue-google-autocomplete
  id="map"
  classname="form-control"
  placeholder="Start typing"
  v-on:placechanged="getAddressData"
/>
```

It's demo is not working today due to exceeding the limit of free requests per day, but it seems legitimate.

If you want to do it on your own anyway, i suggest to check what `this` points to inside `fillInAddress` using the debugger. Perhaps binding context would help.

```js
autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress.bind(this))
```

Comment: I updated my question, but I'm having another issue. Can you take a look towards the bottom of my post under UPDATED?

Comment: I have never worked with google maps, but unless you've created some validation yourself it looks like google maps component is throwing some validation errors. I would suggest to take a look at the documentation and it's examples because im out of ideas